# Docker- Image and Container to build and run an Executable file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

Am new to Docker technologies, I have build an executable file in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 machine.

Am looking to dockerize this executable file. I have build an Image and Container but the exe file is not being execute.

Here is my work so far:

Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","Controller.exe"]
CMD ["Controller.exe","RUN"]
```

Command used to create Image:

```
docker build -t imagename:version
```

Command used to create controller:

```
docker run -it --name Controller_name Image_ID run
```

Am trying to start the controller, but the controller is not starting

[image]

I have performed docker logs and here is the information in the log file.
`A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\app'.`

Comment: with `docker ps -a` you can also see the containers that are stopped. And with `docker logs <container_name>` you can see the log output of that container. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: As per your instructions i have performed the logs and here is the result in log file.                                                                                                               `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\app'. `